# Create a power automate flow which will return the SharePoint site owners

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp

I need to create a Power automate flow which will return the site owners of the SharePoint.

After this I will be creating a powerapp in which you put the site name and the app will return the SharePoint site owners of that site. This will be triggered in power automate flow. Hence first need to create the flow to return SharePoint site owners.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch users from particular SharePoint group or trying to fetch site collection administrators (SCA)?

Comment: Site owners of the Any SharePoint site. Creating PowerApp where you can put a Site name and it will return the Site Owners of that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Send an HTTP request to SharePoint` action in power automate by passing the below API request in the Uri section

`_api/web/associatedownergroup/users`

This will give you the list of users who are part of the SharePoint site owner group.
Then you can parse the response of above action using `Parse JSON`, which will help you to iterate through `results` ( which basically will contain the information about the users). Further you can just return the list of users which whatever information you need to pass to the power apps by using  the `Respond to a PowerApp or flow` action.

Comment: @prathamesh-bhalerao Important: Above API will not return Owners for the Teams Site connected with Office 365 Group.  Let me know if you do have that scenario as well